# sharepoint 2010. SPField set control for edit and preview

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, custom-fields, custom-field-type

I need to add custom editor for my created sharepoint field. 
How can i set control both for edit mode and preview mode. Will be two different controls!

I found that i can override **FieldRenderingControl**.
But how to determine that current mode is edit or preview?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom field render control ([BaseFieldControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.basefieldcontrol.aspx)) check on the member "ControlMode", which is of type [SPControlMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spcontrolmode.aspx).

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
  base.CreateChildControls();

  if (ControlMode == SPControlMode.Display)
  {
    // create controls for display view form
  }
  else
  {
    // create controls for edit/new form
  }
```

Also have a look on the [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield_members.aspx) "GetFieldValueAsText()" and "GetFieldValueAsHtml()" inherited from [SPField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms438369.aspx). Since the are used to display the fields content in non-form location. For instance in list view or in the version history.